# Procmail cyrillic conversion

Tags: ubuntu, scripting, procmail, fetchmail

I wrote a script for `fetchmail` to take mail from an account and pipe the messages to `procmail` for it to apply filters and save attachments. I used filter for Subject of the message, but I have cyrillics in the source subject, so when `fetchmail` pipes the messages to `procmail` the final subject starts with UTF-8 encryption and then just gibberish.

`Procmail` script looks like this:

```
:0fHw
*^Content-Type:*text/plain; *charset="?(iso-8859-1|US-ASCII|UNKNOWN-8BIT)"?
| formail -i "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=windows-1251"

:0
*^content-Type:
{
:0c
$HOME/fetchmail/backup

:0f
*^Subject:.*ASVA
| uudeview -i +a +o -p $HOME/fetchmail/attachments -
}
```

The scripts works perfectly on latinic subjects, but because of cyrillic subjects my filter doesn't see the keyword I've put.
How can I convert the subject to be shown in proper cyrillics and latinics? 
I have language packs installed, locals set to ru_RU:UTF-8 and when I write in cyrillics it's shown properly.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're talking about [RFC 2047: MIME encoding for email headers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047.html). Further RFCs have since then augmented this RFC to allow more character sets and to optionally include a language specification.

Because the initial email and MIME specifications included the assumption that headers would only contain strict US-ASCII, the header encoding is completely separate issue from the MIME encoding of the message body.

The format is:

```
=? <character-set> [*language] ? <encoding-letter> ? <text> ?=
```

`<encoding-letter>` will be either Q for quoted-printable, or B for base64 encoding. If the message seems to be totally gibberish, I'd assume you're seeing base64. Both the character set name and the encoding letter are case-insensitive.

So you might see:

```
Subject: =?utf-8?b?SWYgeW91IGNhbiByZWFkIHRoaXMsIHlvdSB1bmRlcnN0b29kIHRoZSBleGFtcGxlLgo=?=
```

Or with a language ID added:

```
Subject: =?utf-8*en?b?SWYgeW91IGNhbiByZWFkIHRoaXMsIHlvdSB1bmRlcnN0b29kIHRoZSBleGFtcGxlLgo=?=
```

Manual decoding example:

```
$ echo "SWYgeW91IGNhbiByZWFkIHRoaXMsIHlvdSB1bmRlcnN0b29kIHRoZSBleGFtcGxlLgo=" | base64 -d
If you can read this, you understood the example.
```

The fact that your existing Procmail script includes forcing the labelling of character set encodings `iso-8859-1`, `US-ASCII` and `UNKNOWN-8BIT` as `windows-1251` indicates that your actual problem might be mislabelled character encoding. In other words:

- an old email client emits `windows-1251` cyrillics without labelling them as such, possibly also in the headers
- on the way, the email passes through a mail server that either does not properly announce that it can handle 8-bit mail encodings cleanly, or is zealous about enforcing the labelling of all character sets other than plain US-ASCII.

In this situation, a MTA needs to encode and label the 8-bit characters to get the mail passed on. But if the 8-bit characters are unlabelled, only the originating mail client knows for sure what the character set actually is.

The problem about labelling character sets after the fact is that identifying the character set may require human-level understanding about whether the content makes sense interpreted as a particular character set or not. So you'll end up using heuristics, which will sometimes be wrong.

For example, if you receive an email that is actually properly encoded in `iso-8859-1`, your script will mislabel it as `windows-1251`, causing any Nordic/West-European accented characters to appear as random non-sensical Cyrillics. But if this is rarer than receiving `windows-1251` encoded messages mislabelled as `iso-8859-1`, it may be your choice to accept that risk and that's fine.

I think you'll have to investigate your problematic messages to find out how their `Subject:` headers are actually encoded. Are they:

- plain unlabelled `windows-1251`?
- actually valid `base64`-encoded UTF-8?
- or `windows-1251` that has been `base64`-encoded and mislabelled as UTF-8?

Unfortunately `procmail` and its companion `formail` may be insufficient in getting the `Subject:` header in unencoded form. They have been [unmaintained since year 2001](https://lwn.net/Articles/416901/), and [even their author now suggests moving on to something else](https://marc.info/?l=openbsd-ports&m=141634350915839&w=2). But if you wish to keep using `procmail` for now, you'll need something like this script:

https://github.com/akkana/scripts/blob/master/decodemail.py

I haven't done significant `procmail` scripting in about 10 years, so the example below may be wrong or there might be a better way to do this. But perhaps this is useful in explaining how the problem might be solved...

You would have to first decode the contents of the `Subject:` header and store it into a variable:

```
:0 h
SUBJDECODED=| decodemail.py Subject:

:0 h
SUBJWASRAW=| formail -xSubject: | recode windows-1251..UTF-8
```

To correct for mislabeled encodings, you might then have to recode the character set from whatever it actually is to UTF-8 used by your system:

```
SUBJWASWIN1251=`echo "$SUBJDECODED" | recode windows-1251..UTF-8`
```

If there are multiple possible encodings, you may have to create multiple variables like this.

Then you can match by any version of the subject:

```
:0
* SUBJWASRAW ?? your-subject-regexp-here
{
    # Here the subject was raw windows-1251 without any encoding at all.
    # The variable has it converted to valid UTF-8 used by this system,
    # so now the header can be rewritten in an useful form.
    # (This example leaves the subject as raw unlabelled UTF-8 which 
    # may or may not be acceptable to whatever you use to view your email with.
    # But on modern RFC 6532 compliant mail clients 
    # in a system that uses UTF-8 throughout it may actually be OK.)

    :0 f
    | formail -i "Subject: $SUBJWASRAW"
}

:0
* SUBJWASWIN1251 ?? your-subject-regexp-here
{
    # regexp matched, so we know the subject was windows-1251 
    # mislabeled as UTF-8. Fix it.
    :0 f
    | formail -i "Subject: $SUBJWASWIN1251"
}

:0
* SUBJDECODED ?? your-subject-regexp-here
{
    # regexp matched to subject decoded according to existing label
    # so we know that it was validly labelled. But it still needs to
    # be rewritten as it may have been something other than UTF-8.
    :0 f
    | formail -i "Subject: $SUBJDECODED"
}

# Any further rules should be able to match on the subject as usual.
```

Note: the `your-subject-regexp-here` regular expression should not include the `^Subject:.*` prefix, as the variables will only contain the *value* of the `Subject:` header.

Comment: I guess you mean `* SUBJWASRAW ?? your-subject-regexp-here` with `??` to examine the variable.

Comment: That's right, sorry about that.